# Linear layout is not scrolling with recycler view in nested scroll view

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedrecyclerview

please help!

I'm trying to create a layout where I have a LinearLayout containing an ImageView and a TextView alongside a horizontal RecyclerView. I want both the LinearLayout and the RecyclerView to behave as a single horizontally scrollable unit. When I scroll the RecyclerView, the LinearLayout should scroll with it, as if it's the first item of the RecyclerView.

```
     <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<!-- LinearLayout with ImageView and TextView -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- ... ImageView and TextView ... -->
</LinearLayout>

<!-- RecyclerView -->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
       </LinearLayout>
```

In my Java code, I've set setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) for the RecyclerView, but it's not working as expected. The RecyclerView and the LinearLayout are not scrolling together.

I've also tried using a HorizontalScrollView, but the RecyclerView scrolls separately from the LinearLayout.

Can someone help me achieve the desired behavior where both the LinearLayout and the RecyclerView scroll together horizontally, as if they are a single unit?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!